# Mange minimized windows at bottom horizontally in extjs rather than overlapping

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am using Extjs  where I am handling multiple minimized windows. When I click on the minimize button I am aligning the window to bottom left corner. But in case of multiple windows, the minimized windows are getting overlapped on one another at the bottom left corner. They are not aligned horizontally. How can I arrange the minimized windows horizontally at bottom of the screen.

Below is my sample code.

```
 Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        minimizable: true,
        title: 'first win',
        listeners: {
            "minimize": function (window, opts) {
                window.collapse();
                window.setWidth(150);
                window.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'bl-bl')
            }
        }

    }).show();
       Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        minimizable: true,
        title: 'second win',
        listeners: {
            "minimize": function (window, opts) {
                window.collapse();
                window.setWidth(150);
                window.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'bl-bl')
            }
        }

    }).show();
       Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        minimizable: true,
        title: 'third win',
        listeners: {
            "minimize": function (window, opts) {
                window.collapse();
                window.setWidth(150);
                window.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'bl-bl')
            }
        }

    }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an array to keep track of the minimized window. This will help you to know whether to align to the viewport or to another minimized window.